mouse click not registering in roblox studio
I'm making a simple flappy bird game in roblox studio
I made this code for the bird so that the bird would fall but go up when the left mouse button is clicked and the code would run until the bird touched another part but everytime i click the bird is still in it's place unmoving
local bird = game.Workspace.bird
bird.Anchored = true
local uis = game.UserInputService
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local gravity = -1
local Parts = bird:GetTouchingParts()
local bird_flap = bird.Position + Vector3.new(0, 10, 0)
local gravity_cancel = false
local script_start = false
uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input) -- detect when to start script
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        script_start = true
    end
end)
if script_start then
    while not Parts do
        gravity_cancel = false
        if not Parts then
            task.wait(0.5)
            gravity = gravity * 2 -- make the bird fall on exponentially increasing increments
        end
        uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
            if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then -- make the gravity factor reset when clicked
                gravity_cancel = true
            end
        end)
        if not gravity_cancel then --make the bird fall
            bird.Position = bird.Position + Vector3.new(0, gravity, 0)
        else -- make the bird go up or "flap"
            bird.Position = bird_flap
            gravity = -1
        end
        task.wait(0.1)
    end
end


looks like you don't know what your code is doing. a) your script basically does nothing because you connect an event handler and then immediately skip the rest of your script because your condition is false. b) you're connecting more event handlers in a while loop. this doesn't make any sense in this case. make sure you understand what uis.InputBegan:Connect does and how to use it properly.

thank u @Piglet but how do i add code that checks if left mouse button is clicked in the while loop without breaking the script

I suggest you take a step back and learn some basic logic first and also read something about event handling.  for example you start loop while not Parts and 2 lines later you do if not parts that doesn't make any sense. how should Parts change within 2 lines of code that don't touch it.  same for if start_script where you just assigned false to it a few lines before. then again the same with gravity_cancel.  you lack very basic understanding of logic and control structures which makes you struggle implementing your game.

Read this https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/events    and understand that uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)... just tells the game to call the anonymous function whenever an input begins.  so doiing this once is enough.  so if you want the game to do something on a mouse click, that provided function is the place to implement that.   your movements also don't make any sense. I think you should spend more time reading documentations and thinking about your game. you seem pretty lost. I don*t want to discourage you but is is very important to understand the basics
